# numberstringnum or numberstring in lowercase

Tags: numbering, strings, cases, fmtcount

I have tried a lot to use the `\numberstringnum` and `\numberstring` macros but it appears incomplete or even do not appear on the text.

So I tested in the female version, like below:

```
\numberstringnum{\stotal{croquis}}[f]
```

and it's ok, but if I delete [f] or try another gender [m], or [n] the error persists.

How can I use this function in lowercase??

The function `\Numberstringnum` or `\Numberstring` works great, but I cannot transform it to lowercase like `\lowercase\Numberstringnum f`.

How can I make it?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fmtcount}


\begin{document}

\Numberstring{page}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{1}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{2}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{3}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{4}[f] 

\numberstring{page}[f] 
\numberstringnum{1}[f] 
\numberstringnum{2}[f] 
\numberstringnum{3}[f] 
\numberstringnum{4}[f] 

\Numberstring{page}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{1}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{2}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{3}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{4}[m] 

\numberstring{page}[m] 
\numberstringnum{1}[m] 
\numberstringnum{2}[m] 
\numberstringnum{3}[m] 
\numberstringnum{4}[m] 

\end{document}
```

And the anwer:

```
Uma Uma Duas Três Quatro
uma uma duas três quatro
Um Um Dois Três Quatro
```

The error:

```
Error in main.tex (line 30): Argument of \@unitstring has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30 \numberstring{page}[m]

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

I think the problem is about the language - portuguese, I tested english and french and it's ok, but portugueses I get this error for lowercase, and \lowercase{\Numberstring{}} have no effect.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Or you highlight it and press `CTRL-K`.

Comment: Where is `\stotal` defined? Is it a counter value or the counter itself?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

Comment: That is not a minimally working example.

Comment: There is something strange going one with `\@unitstring`. Portuguese is a language with male and female nouns, isn't it?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: There might an error in the `fc-portuges.def` file when `\numberstring{page}[m]` is used. It complains about an extra `}`. I traced it back to line approx. 583 with content `\edef#2{\@@fc@numstr\@unitstring{\@strctr}}%`, but I do not understand why.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Looks like it's [this issue](https://github.com/nlct/fmtcount/issues/10).

Answer (score 5):

Using the commands from `\fmtcount` package it is important to set the language and using either the counter **name** or the counter **value**!

Generally, all commands ending with `...num` expect a counter value, where as the similar commands without suffix `num` expect the counter name.

If `\stotal` delivers in fact a counter name, then the `\numstring{` versions has to be used, if it yields the counter value, the `\numstringnum` 
way has to be walked.

The small example code shows the output for english and french language in tables, using several variants and gender specifications as well as a small overview for the case `[m]` (or basically none) is specified.

The manual states, that `\FCloadlang` should be used in the preamble, but it seems to work afterwards too.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}


\newcounter{DemoCounter}

\setcounter{DemoCounter}{3}

\newcommand{\CounterOutput}[3][]{
\footnotesize
 \textcolor{blue}{#2{#3}[#1]}%
}%


\newcommand{\tableline}[4]{%
\tt{$\backslash$#1} & #3 & #4 & \CounterOutput[f]{\csname #1\endcsname}{#2} & \CounterOutput[m]{\csname #1\endcsname}{#2} & \CounterOutput[n]{\csname #1\endcsname}{#2} \tabularnewline
}%



\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\FCloadlang{english}

\small
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\scshape English}\tabularnewline
       & Input & Value & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Gender} \tabularnewline
Macro &        &       &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{m} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n} \tabularnewline
\hline
\tableline{numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
& && & \setcounter{DemoCounter}{17} \tabularnewline
\tableline{numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\end{tabular}


\setcounter{DemoCounter}{5}

\begin{itemize}

\item Using the counter \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{name}} DemoCounter:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{verbatim}\numberstring{DemoCounter}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\numberstring{DemoCounter}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\Numberstring{DemoCounter}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\Numberstring{DemoCounter}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\NUMBERstring{DemoCounter}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\NUMBERstring{DemoCounter}}
\end{enumerate}

\item Using the counter \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{value}} of DemoCounter:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{verbatim}\numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\Numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\Numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\NUMBERstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\NUMBERstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}

\newpage%
%%%% Now french

\selectlanguage{french}
\FCloadlang{french}

\small
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\scshape French}\tabularnewline
       & Input & Value & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Gender} \tabularnewline
Macro &        &       &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{m} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n} \tabularnewline
\hline
\tableline{numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
& && & \setcounter{DemoCounter}{17} \tabularnewline
\tableline{numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstring}{DemoCounter}{Counter Name}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{Numberstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\tableline{NUMBERstringnum}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}{Counter Value}{\number\value{DemoCounter}}%
\end{tabular}


\setcounter{DemoCounter}{5}

\begin{itemize}

\item Using the counter \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{name}} DemoCounter:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{verbatim}\numberstring{DemoCounter}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\numberstring{DemoCounter}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\Numberstring{DemoCounter}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\Numberstring{DemoCounter}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\NUMBERstring{DemoCounter}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\NUMBERstring{DemoCounter}}
\end{enumerate}

\item Using the counter \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{value}} of DemoCounter:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{verbatim}\numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\Numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\Numberstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}}
\item \begin{verbatim}\NUMBERstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}\end{verbatim} yields \textcolor{red}{\NUMBERstringnum{\number\value{DemoCounter}}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**If there is no neutral gender in the corresponding language, `fmtcount` uses the corresponding word from another language in the `babel` setting or (probably) `english`.** (see output in the French table)

**Edit**
There seems to be a problem with `fmtcount` support for Portuguese language.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in `fmtcount`. It will be fixed in the next version (2.04) but the following is an interim solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@@unitstringportuges[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
    zero%
    \or um%
    \or dois%
    \or tr\^es%
    \or quatro%
    \or cinco%
    \or seis%
    \or sete%
    \or oito%
    \or nove%
  \fi
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Numberstring{page}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{1}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{2}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{3}[f] 
\Numberstringnum{4}[f] 

\numberstring{page}[f] 
\numberstringnum{1}[f] 
\numberstringnum{2}[f] 
\numberstringnum{3}[f] 
\numberstringnum{4}[f] 

\Numberstring{page}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{1}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{2}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{3}[m] 
\Numberstringnum{4}[m] 

\numberstring{page}[m] 
\numberstringnum{1}[m] 
\numberstringnum{2}[m] 
\numberstringnum{3}[m] 
\numberstringnum{4}[m] 

\end{document}
```