# fmtcount package error on gender option

Tags: fmtcount

I'm trying to change *\thechapter* using **fmtcount** to appear the count with ordinal number. The code I am using is:

```
\let\ordinal\relax % to avoid a spurious warning
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ORDINALstring{chapter}[f]}
```

But when I run that code, with pdflatex, I get the following error:

**! Package fmtcount Error: Invalid gender option `F'.**

For some reason he interprets as capital, even putting in tiny. I tried adding the commands on gender to add the M and F options (capitalized), but did not succeed. Anyone have some idea?

All the code is here:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}

\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona}

\usepackage[BCOR=8.25mm]{typearea}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.2}


\let\ordinal\relax % to avoid a spurious warning
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ORDINALstring{chapter}[f]}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\centering}{\filcenter\MakeUppercase{\thechapter} PARTE}{1em}{}   

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Lição de Violão}  


%Just to only to test the gender type
\ordinalstringnum{1}[f]

Como de hábito, Policarpo Quaresma, mais conhecido por Major Quaresma, bateu em casa às quatro e quinze da tarde. Havia mais de vinte anos que isso acontecia. Saindo do Arsenal de Guerra, onde era subsecretário, bongava pelas confeitarias algumas frutas, comprava um queijo, às vezes, e sempre o pão da padaria francesa.

Não gastava nesses passos nem mesmo uma hora, de forma que, às três e quarenta, por aí assim, tomava o bonde, sem erro de um minuto, ia pisar a soleira da porta de sua casa, numa rua afastada de São Januário, bem exatamente às quatro e quinze, como se fosse a aparição de um astro, um eclipse, enfim um fenômeno matematicamente determinado, previsto e predito.

(...)

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `fmtcount` has a bug in it's Portuguese translations. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174960/numberstringnum-or-numberstring-in-lowercase for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to stop the `[f]` from being uppercased:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}

\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona}

\usepackage[BCOR=8.25mm]{typearea}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.2}

\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\let\ordinal\relax % to avoid a spurious warning
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\lowercase{\ORDINALstring{chapter}[f]}}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\centering}{\filcenter\MakeUppercase{\thechapter} PARTE}{1em}{}   

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Lição de Violão}  


%Just to only to test the gender type
\ordinalstringnum{1}[f]

Como de hábito, Policarpo Quaresma, mais conhecido por Major Quaresma, bateu em casa às quatro e quinze da tarde. Havia mais de vinte anos que isso acontecia. Saindo do Arsenal de Guerra, onde era subsecretário, bongava pelas confeitarias algumas frutas, comprava um queijo, às vezes, e sempre o pão da padaria francesa.

Não gastava nesses passos nem mesmo uma hora, de forma que, às três e quarenta, por aí assim, tomava o bonde, sem erro de um minuto, ia pisar a soleira da porta de sua casa, numa rua afastada de São Januário, bem exatamente às quatro e quinze, como se fosse a aparição de um astro, um eclipse, enfim um fenômeno matematicamente determinado, previsto e predito.

(...)

\end{document}
```